# can I get node to output commas in number strings without bringing in i18n?

Tags: node.js, internationalization

Not that adding a require is a big deal but the [node docs suggest that you don't need it:](http://nodemanual.org/latest/js_doc/Number.html#Number.toLocaleString)

```
// from the docs: 
var number = 3500;
console.log(number.toLocaleString()); // Displays "3,500" in English locale
```

Except that doesn't happen:

```
$ node
> var n = 1238909880
undefined
> n.toLocaleString() 
'1238909880'
> n.toLocaleString('en-US' )  // docs on node don't suggest this, but on MDN they do so...
'1238909880'
> process.env.LANG
'en_US.UTF-8'
```

Do I have to bring in i18n to get commas in my numbers? There's nothing about that on the nodejs docs for Number.toLocaleString. My `LANG` looks correct, as far as I know, which isn't far. Tried setting process.env.LANG to 'en-US' and the output didn't change.

Comment: Yeah, the official docs are [here.](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/)  Thanks though, totally stealing your comma regex haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(waited a few days for other answers)

Looks like this is a known issue and the docs that I found are not official. I was unable to find any official docs of this behavior. MDN docs assume a browser is present (which would have i18n). V8 outside of the browser is poorly documented.

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/4689

> bnoordhuis commented:
>
> This is arguably a V8 bug. It ignores locale settings. In fact, all date and number formatting logic is hard-coded.
>
> The reason it works in Chrome and Chromium is that those projects use v8-i18n on top of V8. I don't think that's a direction we want to take. It depends on libicu and that's a massive library. We would have to bundle it and that would increase our already large source tree by another 85 MB and ~500,000 LoC.

My solution was this (coffee):

```
Number::withCommas = ->
  parts = this.toString().split(".")
  parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
  parts.join "."
```

Alternate solution: Use [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com). It's nifty.

Comment: See my other response.

Comment: Also, see the rest of the issue and PR quoted, and for much further discussion.

Answer (score 2):

This will change. Working on getting Intl on by default in node. See https://github.com/joyent/node/pull/7719

**EDIT** If you download node v0.12, Intl is on by default.

Comment: I have node 6 and it still doesn't work to me on linux. But it works on a mac :/

Comment: @Mr.Goferito What wasn't working? Does "npm install full-icu" help?

Comment: Cool. It's doesn't work just by requiring it, but it gave me the clue. `NODE_ICU_DATA=icudt58l.dat node ...` did the trick, being icudl58l.dat the full icu data file. Thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Goferito yeah, i've been trying to make what you want work for a year. Tricky details are the platform dependent parts… https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3460