# toLocaleString() not returning the right date format in node.js

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, timestamp

**In chrome's console:** 

`(new Date(Date.now())).toLocaleString()` returns `"9/5/2014 9:43:08 PM"`

`new Date(Date.now())` returns `'Fri Sep 05 2014 21:43:08 GMT+0530 (IST)'`

**In node.js REPL/app:** 

`(new Date(Date.now())).toLocaleString()` returns `'Fri Sep 05 2014 21:43:18 GMT+0530 (IST)'` which is the same as running `new Date(Date.now())`

What is the change I need to do to get the same output format as chrome.

Comment: If you need to nicely (and consistently) format a date string, I'd take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com). It's available for the browser and as an npm module.

Comment: I have the same problem in node v4.1.1 in windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using .toLocaleString() in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199909/using-tolocalestring-in-node-js)