# toLocaleDateString is different using the same language

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom, jestjs

I'm using this code.:

```
date.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR')
```

- In my chrome browser the result is.: 9/13/2016
- When I run the tests
  in local.: 2016-09-13
- When I runt the tests in Circle CI.: 9/13/2016

What it happens?

Ps.: I'm using Jest and JSDom for my tests.

Comment: try `new Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-BR').format(date)`  Also, [check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21413757/tolocaledatestring-changes-in-ie11)

Comment: toLocaleDateString is not supported in some of your environments. See this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199909/using-tolocalestring-in-node-js).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `toLocaleDateString` [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) for set a fixed format.

```js
var date = new Date();
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' };
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', options));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add "LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8" in the param test in package.json to fix it

```
"test": "LC_ALL=\"en_US.UTF-8\" npm run test",
```

Answer (score -2):

Why do not use moment.js? It's simple and minimalist library to handle dates server side and client side, locales depend on the system and few things more, use moment and you will be sure the correct format [moment.js](https://momentjs.com)