# toLocaleString('en-IN') formatting different in browser and node.js environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, localization, internationalization

```
const x = (1234567890).toLocaleString('en-IN');
const y = (1234567890).toLocaleString('hi-IN');
```

Both x and y results in `"1,234,567,890"` in Node.js
but `"1,23,45,67,890"` in browsers.

Any alternative to fix this problem in Node.js. I want browser output in Node.js too.

> Node version: 8.9

Comment: Possible duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199909/using-tolocalestring-in-node-js)

Comment: Do your system have installed both `en-IN` and `hi-IN`?