# toLocaleString not getting the language I set on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, locale

Im on node.js editing a server side file and I want to get the date in mexican spanish format like this:

```js
const bdate = new Date(1980, 4-1, 3);
const birthdate = bdate.toLocaleString('es-MX', { month: 'short', year : 'numeric', day : 'numeric' });
console.log(birthdate);
```

but this produces `Apr 3, 1980` whereas it should be: `3-abr-1980`

This code works fine on a client side file but not here. What is wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Im on firefox but I have the same problem on chrome as well.

Comment: On the snippet it works. Maybe because im on node.js server side?

Comment: Seems like it is, node.js is the culprit. Im closing this question and opening a new one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using .toLocaleString() in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199909/using-tolocalestring-in-node-js)

Comment: I did have a look at that but its very old. Maybe there is a new alternative out there?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the date format you want with just `"es"` language instead of "es-MX" and then just substitute the spaces for `-`. Another solution would be based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3552493/9801177), you can achieve the same result with `Intl.DateTimeFormat`

I provided some examples here:

```js
const bdate = new Date(1980, 4-1, 3);
const birthdate = bdate.toLocaleString('es', { month: 'short', year : 'numeric', day : 'numeric' }).replaceAll(" ", "-");

console.log(birthdate)


function join(t, a, s) {
   function format(m) {
      let f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es', m);
      return f.format(t);
   }
   return a.map(format).join(s);
}


let a = [{day: 'numeric'}, {month: 'short'}, {year: 'numeric'}];
let s = join(bdate, a, '-');
console.log(s);

let ye = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es', { year: 'numeric' }).format(bdate);
let mo = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es', { month: 'short' }).format(bdate);
let da = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('es', { day: 'numeric' }).format(bdate);
console.log(`${da}-${mo}-${ye}`);
```

Comment: thanks for the effort but isnt there a shorter way around?

Comment: The first option just adds a `replaceAll`, that's the shortest version I could find, otherwise you'll need to add another package that can handle fate formats more easily