# jest unit tests failing in gitlab pipeline for component using Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am getting an error `Value shortGeneric out of range for Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString options property timeZoneName` for a react component using `Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString` in gitlab pipeline.

The tests are passing on local env.

The components `ErrorBoundary` renders the above error.

the component uses below code
`date?.toLocaleTimeString("en", { timeZoneName: "shortGeneric", hourCycle: "h12", hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric", }, )`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23200062 this answer says to install `intl` but couldn't understand how to use it